# RMAN backup into Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, rman

I want to take Oracle database backup using RMAN directly into the Google Cloud Storage

I am unable to find the plugin to use to take the RMAN backups into Cloud Storage. We have a plugin for Amazon S3 and am looking for one such related to Google Cloud Storage.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's an official way of doing this. Although I did file a Feature Request for the Cloud Storage engineering team to look into that you can find [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/141977464).

I recommend you to star the Feature Request, for easy visibility and access, allowing you to view its status updates. The Cloud Storage team might ask questions there too.

Comment: Thanks Maxim. Will post more details if i get around some other issues related to this. Am working on a POC to automate Oracle DB migration to GCP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [gcsfuse](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) to mount GCS bucket as file systems on your machine and use RMAN to create backups there.

You can find more information about gcsfuse on its [github page](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/). Here are the basic steps to mount a bucket and run RMAN:

1. Create a bucket `oracle_bucket`. Check that it doesn't have a retention policy defined on it (it looks like gcsfuse has some issues with retention policies).

Please have a look at [mounting.md](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/mounting.md) that describes credentials for GCS. For example, I created a service account with Storage Admin role and created a JSON key for it.

2. Next, set up credentials for gcsfuse on your machine. In my case, I set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to the path to JSON key from step 1. Run:

```
sudo su - oracle  
mkdir ./mnt_bucket  
gcsfuse --dir-mode 755 --file-mode 777 --implicit-dirs --debug_fuse oracle_bucket ./mnt_bucket
```

From gcsfuse docs:

> Important: You should run gcsfuse as the user who will be using the
>   file system, not as root. Do not use sudo.

3. Configure RMAN to create a backup in `mnt_bucket`. For example:

```
configure controlfile autobackup format for device type disk to '/home/oracle/mnt_bucket/%F'; 
configure channel device type disk format '/home/oracle/mnt_bucket/%U';
```

4. After you run `backup database` you'll see a backup files created in your GCS bucket.